# How to avoid the faint display of tracks when using the time slider of Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

After playing a track with the Time Slider, I often get a faint but clearly visible track remaining. Anyone know why and how to fix it please?

Here's an example. The GPX track has been played once and now I'm stuck with this faint remainder.
[image: timeslider]

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/GE-TimeSliderFaintPuzzle.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you would like to have _fixed_? - The parts of the track which are **outside** of your specified time range are displayed in a _faded, semi-transparent style_ in Google Earth, but _not completely hidden_. (Like in the screen-shot you posted.) If you want to show the complete track, divide out the two parts of the time slider to the leftmost and the rightmost position. Push them together to fade (parts of) the track. I am not aware of an option to completely hide instead of just fade the track though.

Comment: Thanks lavarider.

Further clarification:

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/GE-TimeSliderPuzzle%231.jpg)

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/GE-TimeSliderPuzzle-2.jpg)

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/GE-TimeSliderPuzzle%233.jpg)

So if I understand correctly, it looks a track with time data is **always** visible? If so, seems an odd design choice? I'm almost sure that it hasn't been like that in all previous versions.

-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK

Answer (score 3):

*Your observation is a result of two limitations within Google Earth:* 
The import options of GPX to KML are quite restricted, and so is the style control of information with time-stamps.

*(My desriptions are based on GE version 7.1.2.2041 Linux. The [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) / [standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml/) is device-independent though.)*

---

### GPX import limitations

Unfortunately, during the import of a GPX file, Google Earth offers very few options:

> - *Create KML tracks*
> - *Create KML LineStrings*  (compatible to GE < 5.2)

If you check  ***Create KML tracks***, GE creates a KML file, which contains **one single placemark**. This placemark is composed of a `<gx:Track>` element with all the information like all time stamps and coordinates. *(This enables some advanced functionality like the interpolation of time/position information between points.)*

If you check ***Create KML LineStrings***, GE creates a KML file  which basically consists of two parts:

- a *"Points"* folder, which contains a **series of placemarks**, each one being of `<Point>` type with its specific single time stamp.
- a single `<LineString>` placemark, which contains the complete track line but not any time stamp information.

However, it is **not possible to generate a KML "track" which is stringed together by a series of small, time-stamped `LineStrings`**, each one representing the small connection between two adjacent coordinate pairs.

---

*With this in mind, have a look how Google Earth displays these (internally created) KML files:*

### How time-stamped information is displayed in Google Earth

*If your data contains timestamps, the time-slider is displayed, and you are to define a time range.*

- placemark is *completely out of the defined time range*: **not displayed**.
- placemark has single time stamp, and is completely inside the defined time range: **displayed normally**
- placemark has multiple time-stamps, and is ***partly** out of the defined time range*: **faded display** of the parts outside the time-range, **full display** of the parts within the time range. An arrow marks the position at at the end of the selected time-span.

*Your track is displayed this last way. At least one point of the track is within the specified time range: In your case, it is the starting point of the track at 12/19/2013 8:48:29pm, located at the arrow icon.*

**There is *no [style](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style) option* to control the fading in any way**. (You can only define a *normal* and a *highlight* (i.e. hover) style using a [StyleMap](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#stylemap)). *Depending on the overall transparency, the faded parts are more or less visible, but they are always faded.* Particularly, there is no option to completely hide instead of fade parts of a track.

---

*So merging this information, what can you do?*

## How to avoid the faded display of tracks?

- As a workaround, you could stick with the *"Create KML tracks"* import option, but manually adjust the range offered by the time slider. This way, you are able to completely un-select the track.
  *The `<LookAt>` section of your KML file contains a [`<gx:TimeSpan>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtimestamp) element. You can adjust the time range here.* Also, if your KML file contains multiple tracks, you may be able to select a time range without any visible tracks. **You will not get rid of the faded display of partly visible tracks, though.**
- Use the *"Create KML LineStrings"* import option instead. The name is quite misleading, because this will create point placemarks and one single long path (i.e. one LineString per gpx track). You can expand the generated KML folder and *uncheck "Path"* (which is always displayed since no time stamps are present there). Remaining are the series of points. Only the points within the selected time range are displayed, the ones outside are invisible. No faded stuff here. Your track is displayed as a series of unconnected points though, which may look quite bad.
- **Use a different tool than Google Earth to generate a more sophisticated KML out of your GPX file.** *What you need is a series of very tiny `<LineString>` paths, each with its own time-stamp, which ultimately connect and represent the total track if displayed all together.* This way unselected time-ranges of the track are hidden, but the visible parts are still displayed as a connected line. (By the way, this opens up some additional styling possibilities like different line-styles / colors on different parts of the track.)

---

*What tools do exist to generate a suitable KML (as described above)?*

### Recommendations of GPX to KML converters

[**GPSVisualizer** webpage](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth) is highly recommended. It allows to upload a gpx file and convert it to kml with tons of visualization options. Particularly, you should select *"Add time stamps, if possible: YES"* to preserve the time stamps. ***The produced KML files probably look like you expect.***

I am not aware how other tools perform with respect to styling of their KLM export functionality, but [GPSbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_kml.html) may be worth a look. It has several options to convert or split tracks, so maybe you are successful with it.

Comment: It's an unusual web forum rule that forbids a 'thank you'. For such a thorough reply that clearly took significant time to prepare I've no guilt in breaking it!
I'll investigate GPSVisualizer.
IMO the GE team need to overhaul the Time Slider.

Comment: _If you consider an answer useful, you may upvote it instead of a "thank you" message. (Or even accept it)_ - I totally agree that Google Earth's display options  to visualize time-enabled data are far too limited; especially the time-slider is a very static approach for more sophisticated datasets.